# GNU make not building target

Tags: gnu-make

I'd like to have the following rules:

```
foo_% bar_%:
        @echo "Complex building instructions for $@"

all: foo_xyz bar_xyz
```

and then run 'make all' and get:

```
Complex building instructions for foo_xyz
Complex building instructions for bar_xyz
```

However, because the '%' matches the same string twice (xyz) it is only "built" the first time, so all I get is the first line.

Is there a way to get GNU make to execute the 'echo' twice when '$@' is different the second time? After all, since $@ is different, the build instructions are different :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, multiple pattern targets behave differently from normal targets: Make will consider the recipe responsible for making all patterns.

A way to solve this is to use a define:

```
define complex-rule
$1:
    @echo "Complex building instructions for $$@"
endef

$(eval $(call complex-rule,foo_%))
$(eval $(call complex-rule,bar_%))

all: foo_xyz bar_xyz
```

Note that, since it will be `eval`ed, I escaped `$@` to `$$@` because I want it to be expanded when the recipe runs, not when I `eval` it. On the other hand, I didn't escape `$1` because I want the first argument to expand on `call`.